# Multiple popovers swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to implement a help system like imovie, and i wonder how can I display multiple pop overs in specific locations in one view controller.

[image: imovie screenshot]

Comment: Please post your work-in-progress implementation when asking for programming help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that these are actually full blown `UIPopoverController`'s. If you're trying to create help messages like this screenshot, I would create a custom view and have an enclosing transparent view on top of the controller where each of these help "popovers" would be subviews. The reason you don't need a full `UIPopoverController` is that there will not be user interaction on the popover itself.

Comment: I started working that way, but I thought that it was more of a work-around! thanks anyway